# Threshold image using opencv (Java)

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, tesseract

I am working with Opencv for my project. I need to convert the image below to threshold image

[image: Original Image]

I tried this function:

```
Imgproc.threshold(imgGray, imgThreshold, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY + Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
```

But the result was not so good, as you see below

[image: threshold]

So I tried the `adaptiveThreshold function`:

```
Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(imgGray, imgThreshold, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 11, 2);
```

and it resulted:

[image: adaptiveThreshold]

I just expect a binary image with white background and black text only, no black area or noise ( I do not prefer using `Photo.fastNlMeansDenoising` because it takes a lot of time). Please help me with a solution for this.

Also, I am using `Tesseract` for Japanese recognization but the accuracy rate is not good. Do you have any suggestion on better OCR for Japanese, or any method to improve Tesseract quality?

Comment: It's been a long time since I used openCV, so I may be talking nonsense. Can't you search for contours and white everything outside a contour and black everything inside the contour? The result image should be pretty sharp and accurate, given the type of input.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`adaptiveThreshold` is the right choice here. **Just need a litte tuning**.
With these parameters (it's C++, but you can easily translate to Java)

```
Mat1b gray= imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
Mat1b result;
adaptiveThreshold(gray, result, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, THRESH_BINARY, 15, 40);
```

the resulting image is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. This work perfectly for me. I just dont understand the meaning of the last parameter (40). Could you pls explain this?

Comment: @BeeBee It's a constant subtracted from the mean.  Read [opencv doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#adaptivethreshold) for further information

Comment: can show me the java code here even in kotlin is fine need to remove shadow from image

Comment: @Miki I get cannot resolve Mat1b in AndroidStudio and there are no suggestions either. I'm using OpenCV4.2. Could you please suggest how/where to resolve this?

Comment: Mat is defined in org.opencv.core .