# How can I detect squares using opencv4.2 (Android)

Tags: java, image, opencv, android

I am detecting a rectangle and comparing the color to a urine test strip.

How can i detect all of squares? I want to detect the remaining squares in the picture below. I have tried changing the brightness and contrast

Here is my code:

MainActivity.java

```
...
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        ...
                    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                    in.close();
                    Bitmap changeImg = changeBitmapContrastBrightness(img, (float)1, 10);
                    Mat cMap = new Mat();
                    Utils.bitmapToMat(changeImg, cMap);
                    List<MatOfPoint> squres = processImage(cMap);

                    for (int i = 0; i < squres.size(); i++) {
                        setLabel(cMap, String.valueOf(i), squres.get(i));
                    }

                    Bitmap resultBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(cMap.cols(), cMap.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Utils.matToBitmap(cMap, resultBitmap);
                    imgView.setImageBitmap(resultBitmap);
                ...
    }
...
private static List<MatOfPoint> processImage(Mat img){
        ArrayList<MatOfPoint> squares = new ArrayList<>();
        Mat matGray = new Mat();
        Mat matCny = new Mat();
        Mat matBlur = new Mat();
        Mat matThresh = new Mat();
        Mat close = new Mat();
        // 노이즈 제거위해 다운스케일 후 업스케일
//        Imgproc.pyrDown(matInit, matBase, matBase.size());
//        Imgproc.pyrUp(matBase, matInit, matInit.size());
        // GrayScale
        Imgproc.cvtColor(img, matGray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        // Blur
        Imgproc.medianBlur(matGray, matBlur, 5);
        //        // Canny Edge 검출
//        Imgproc.Canny(matBlur, matCny, 0, 255);
//        // Binary
        Imgproc.threshold(matBlur, matThresh, 160, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY_INV);
        Imgproc.morphologyEx(matThresh, close, Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(3,3)));
//        // 노이즈 제거
//        Imgproc.erode(matCny, matCny, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new org.opencv.core.Size(6, 6)));
//        Imgproc.dilate(matCny, matCny, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new org.opencv.core.Size(12, 12)));

        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
        Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
        Imgproc.findContours(close, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
        double min_area = 0;
        double max_area = 10000;
        for(MatOfPoint cnt : contours){
            double contourArea = Imgproc.contourArea(cnt);

            if(contourArea > min_area && contourArea < max_area){
                squares.add(cnt);
            }
        }
        return squares;
    }
```

App result Image

[image]

---

### Original Image

[image]

Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correctly identifying the smaller boxes and ignoring the very large box which is the strip, so the basics are all in place.

It is not recognising the smaller boxes on the strip - given that your contour finding is clearly working this suggests that the threshold value in your threshold function (160 in your code above) may need to be adjusted so it includes the color boxes on the strip which do not have a black contour. The black contour will be definitely detached.

Whatever the root causes you'll probably find the easiest way to debug it is to output and look at the intermediate images generated - this will allow you check visually yourself very quickly the result of your blurring and thresholding.

You could also take a look at using adaptive thresholding if you are working with multiple images and find the threshold is not something you can reliably determine in advance. The documentation is here: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=adaptivethreshold and there is a very nice example in this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31290735/334402

adaptiveThreshold parameters allow you fine tune its behaviour and it is worth experimenting with them see what works best for a given type if image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks to reply Mick.

I used adaptivethreshold function

but still not detect center patch..

Can you please help me more..??

Here is code and result image

`
Mat clone = mat.clone();

Imgproc.cvtColor(clone, clone, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Imgproc.morphologyEx(clone, clone, Imgproc.MORPH_CLOSE, Imgproc.getStructuringElement(Imgproc.MORPH_RECT, new Size(3, 3)));
Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(clone, clone, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 15, 5);
`

Comment: @ggamdi - corrected link in answer so you can see the example. The best way to play around with the parameters in adaptiveThreshold and look at the intermediated images until you find what works for you.